# Reading delimited value from file into a array variable

Tags: bash

I want to read data.txt which has a 2x2 matrix number inside delimited by tab like this:

```
0.5 0.1
0.3 0.2
```

Is there any way to read this file in bash then store it into an array then process it a little then export it to a file again? Like for example in matlab:

```
a=dlmread('data.txt') //read file to array variable a
for i=1:2
   for j=1:2
   b[i][j]=a[i][j]+100
   end
end
dlmwrite(b,'data2.txt') //exporting array value b to data2.txt
```

Comment: `bash` doesn't do multidimensional arrays and bash doesn't do floating point numbers. So, it may not be your ideal candidate.  Unless there's a reason not to, it might be better to use something like `python` or `perl`.

Comment: @FatalError is there another way like just using 1 dimensional array to solve it like inputing the first row to first array and second row to other array?

Answer (score 0):

If the extent of your processing is to something simple like add 100 to every entry, a simple `awk` command like this might work:

```
awk '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF - 1; i++) { printf("%.1f%s", $i + 100, OFS); } printf("%.1f%s", $NF+100, ORS); }' < matrix.txt
```

This just loops through each row and adds 100. It's possible to do more complex operations too, but if you really want toprocess matrices there are better tools (like `python`+`numpy` or `octave`).

It's also possible to use `bash` arrays, but to do any of the operations you'd have to use an external program anyway, since `bash` doesn't handle floating point arithmetic.